# Generic Spring services from external library?

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to define some commonly used or generic service classes that should be used/shared by different projects. These common services should already make use of `@Transactional`, `@Autowired` and other `Spring` related stuff. So, I somehow have to define a spring context for these services to work.

Is it possible to put these services in a single external `jar` library that can then be used/imported by other (child)-projects? How could I create such a "personal framework"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is create a maven (or gradle) module that contains the code you desire to be reusable and also have a spring configuration (either XML or Java Config) that will be imported by the project that uses the module (either with  or having component scanning pick up the @Configuration class of the module).